# Best way to write input section of algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

i have a problem to align the part regarding  the parameter section. So far i have obtained such result:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,parskip=half*,twoside,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[h]
\SetKwInOut{getDerivable}{getFirstInfs($O$, {\normalfont \textit{I}})}
\getDerivable{compute an inference set from \textit{I} used to derive conclusions from $O$ using \textit{I} \\}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
\Input{An ontology $O$ and an inference set \textit{I}}
\Output{\textit{J} $\subseteq$ \textit{I} such that $\forall$$\beta$ $O$ $\vdash_I$ $\beta$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $O$ $\vdash_J$ $\beta$        }


D $\gets$ \{$O$\} \;
\textit{J} $\gets$ \{$\emptyset$\} \;
\While{true}{
            \ForEach {${\gamma}$ $\in$ \textit{I} }{
                        \If{\normalfont{getPremises($\gamma$)} $\subseteq$ \textit{D}}{
                            \textit{C} $\gets$ getConclusion($\gamma$) \;
                            \If{\textit{C} $\notin$ \textit{D}}{
                            \textit{D} $\gets$ \textit{D} $\cup$ \{\textit{C}\} \;     
                            \textit{J} $\gets$ \textit{J} $\cup$ \{$\gamma$\} \;

                            \textbf{break} \;
                            }
                        }
}       

\textbf{break}\;            
\EndWhile}
\textbf{return} J\;
\caption{Compute inferences for derivable conclusions}
\label{alg:getDerivable}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to avoid the space which there is for input and output.
Below there is an example of the desired result
[image]

I hope someone can help me!!

Comment: Can you give a completely compilable code?

Comment: @AndréC i have updated the complete code.

Comment: The code is not compilable. `Undefined control sequence. <argument> ... } \par \textbf {break}\; \EndWhile`

Answer (score 3):

Just replace `\SetKwInOut` with `\SetKwInput`.

According to `algorithm2e`'s manual, section 11.1,

> `\SetKwInOut{Kw}{input}` works as `\SetKwInput{Kw}{input}`. But the position of the ‘:’ is fixed
>   and set by the longest keyword defined by this macro.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,parskip=half*,twoside,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[h]
    \SetKwInput{getDerivable}{getFirstInfs($O$, {\normalfont \textit{I}})}
    \getDerivable{compute an inference set from \textit{I} used to derive conclusions from $O$ using \textit{I} \\}
    \SetKwInput{Input}{Input}
    \SetKwInput{Output}{Output}
    \Input{An ontology $O$ and an inference set \textit{I}}
    \Output{\textit{J} $\subseteq$ \textit{I} such that $\forall$$\beta$ $O$ $\vdash_I$ $\beta$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $O$ $\vdash_J$ $\beta$        }


    D $\gets$ \{$O$\} \;
    \textit{J} $\gets$ \{$\emptyset$\} \;
    \While{true}{
        \ForEach {${\gamma}$ $\in$ \textit{I} }{
            \If{\normalfont{getPremises($\gamma$)} $\subseteq$ \textit{D}}{
                \textit{C} $\gets$ getConclusion($\gamma$) \;
                \If{\textit{C} $\notin$ \textit{D}}{
                    \textit{D} $\gets$ \textit{D} $\cup$ \{\textit{C}\} \;
                    \textit{J} $\gets$ \textit{J} $\cup$ \{$\gamma$\} \;

                    \textbf{break} \;
                }
            }
        }
        \textbf{break}\;
        %\EndWhile
        }
    \textbf{return} J\;
    \caption{Compute inferences for derivable conclusions}
    \label{alg:getDerivable}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively if you want to achieve an alignment of the `:` after Input and Output, use `\ResetInOut{Output}` just after the first `\SetKwInOut` to set the default `InOut` with as the one obtained with `Output` (because Output is longer than Input).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,parskip=half*,twoside,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[h]
    \SetKwInOut{getDerivable}{getFirstInfs($O$, {\normalfont \textit{I}})}
    \getDerivable{compute an inference set from \textit{I} used to derive conclusions from $O$ using \textit{I} \\}
    \ResetInOut{Output}
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
    \SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
    \Input{An ontology $O$ and an inference set \textit{I}}
    \Output{\textit{J} $\subseteq$ \textit{I} such that $\forall$$\beta$ $O$ $\vdash_I$ $\beta$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $O$ $\vdash_J$ $\beta$        }


    D $\gets$ \{$O$\} \;
    \textit{J} $\gets$ \{$\emptyset$\} \;
    \While{true}{
        \ForEach {${\gamma}$ $\in$ \textit{I} }{
            \If{\normalfont{getPremises($\gamma$)} $\subseteq$ \textit{D}}{
                \textit{C} $\gets$ getConclusion($\gamma$) \;
                \If{\textit{C} $\notin$ \textit{D}}{
                    \textit{D} $\gets$ \textit{D} $\cup$ \{\textit{C}\} \;
                    \textit{J} $\gets$ \textit{J} $\cup$ \{$\gamma$\} \;

                    \textbf{break} \;
                }
            }
        }
        \textbf{break}\;
        %\EndWhile
        }
    \textbf{return} J\;
    \caption{Compute inferences for derivable conclusions}
    \label{alg:getDerivable}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]